# Why does this result only apply to primes congruent 3 mod 4?

Tags: number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

Problem statement (and solution):

> Let p be a prime satisfying $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. Show that if the equation $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$ is soluble, then its solution is given by (1):
>   $$x \equiv \pm a^{\frac{p+1}{4}} \pmod{p}$$

Solution:
$x^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$ implies that $(a\mid p) = 1$
So by Euler's criterion:
$a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

if (1) holds, we have:
$x^2 \equiv a^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \equiv a^{\frac{p+1}{2}} * a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv a^p \pmod{p}$

By Fermat's Little Theorem, $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$

This quite obviously also works in the other direction.
My only real question is, why does the problem statement limit the space to primes congruent to 3 mod 4? Why would this exact proof not work for primes congruent 1 mod 4? What am I missing?

Comment: What does $a^{(p+1)/4}$ mean when $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand the statement.  Let's take $p=7$ and $a=2$.  Then $\frac {p+1}4=2$ and $2^2=4$.  We see that $x^2\equiv 4$ is certainly solvable $\pmod 7$, the solutions being $x=\pm 2$, but neither of these is the solution you describe.  What am I missing?

Comment: My apologies, I misstated the question. I've fixed it now

Comment: $-3 \equiv 4 \equiv 2^2 (\mod{7})$ and $3 \equiv -4 \equiv - 2^2 (\mod{7})$ So the example does work, (although yes it does place minuses in weird, non obvious places. Could use more parentheses if you ask me)

Comment: My mistake, misread.  This version is correct.  But it only has meaning if $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.  For $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ we can't even define $a^{(p+1)/4}$ in general.

Comment: right, because we can not guarantee that (p+1)/4 is an integer. (?will never be?) Derp. Thanks and/or sorry for dumb question. (if you want the points, write up an answer and I'll accept)

Comment: It will never be an integer.  If $p=4k+1$ then $p+1=4k+2$ so $\frac {p+1}4=k+\frac 12$.